# Is it possible to place code into the console in R?

Tags: r

Blasphemy I know to ask ***IF*** it is possible to do something in R, but here I am!

I am interested in the ability to create a function that will place code into the console. In other words, if the user types in `f("3+3")` and hits enter then the console will be waiting for the next command with `> 3+3`. Then when the user hits enter, it will return `6` in this case. Possible? Any ideas?

I wish I had more to share but I've never even thought this functionality would be useful before...

Comment: Do you have some code to share? Your question is quite unclear. Do you want R to show `> 3+3` instead of `> ` as prompt?

Comment: I have no code because this is so foreign to a typical R workflow that I don't have anywhere to start with writing code. I tried to clarify what I want with an edit.

Comment: Why would you want the user to press return twice to get an output? Maybe there's a better way to do what you're looking for.

Comment: @Molx, well I thought it unnecessary details for the question at hand, but since you're asking: you know how people often copy the past few lines of code from their console then share it online or want to put it in a source file? And then you have to manually go through and remove all the `>`, `+` and `[1]` and such to make it run? I'm wanting to write a function for the user to put in the ugly code, then have the function return the cleaned up code ready to run.

Comment: When asking a question on SO, there is a need of some context for readers to understand what you think it is obvious.

Comment: It sounds like your main use case would be multi line code, in which case do you want the user to be pressing enter at each line? Or will you be replacing newlines with semi colons to create a single line version of the code? Maybe it would be easier to write a function which processes the script and then runs it with `eval(parse(text=[cleaned_code]))`; or output the cleaned code with `cat` ready to be copy and pasted?

Comment: If you are using the Windows R GUI then copy the code you want to the clipboard including > and [1] and then from the Edit menu at the top choose "Paste commands only".  (Alt-e a   will also do this.)

Comment: I think ping's alternative is probably what you're looking for. It should be easy to recognize code from the console (lines starting with `>` or `+`) and ignore everything else, which is output. In fact, you could even make an web app for that. Nevertheless, if anyone is copying several lines from the console they should probably be writing that in a .R file instead, so teaching the best practices is also a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could do this is to call `system2()` to invoke an external utility that synthesizes keyboard input. I've written a C++ program called `sendkeys` that can do this on Windows by (ultimately) calling [`SendInput()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx). Demo:

```
system2('sendkeys','3\\\\+3');
3+3
## [1] 6
```

(The backslash escaping is necessary because of the way my utility parses its input; + is a metachar that must be escaped to become literal.)

Let me know if you want my C++ code.

Comment: I for one am interested in that utility.

Answer (score 0):

Would that be the kind of function you would need? Maybe it is not a very elegant solution, though.

```
printEval <- function(x){
    cat(">", x,"\n")
    cat ("Press [enter] to continue")
    line <- readline()
    eval(parse(text=x))
}
```

EDIT: Sorry, I just noticed that the eval(parse()) solution was already suggest by @Ping in the comment field right under the question.